# nested asynchronous fetches with Cloudkit?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am relatively new to coding for iOS. In the past week, I've been incorporating CloudKit into my project. One thing I want to do is get the current User recordID. Then, using that recordID, I want to fetch that user's actual record. Currently I am using the following code, which seems to work:

```
self.container.fetchUserRecordID() { recordID, error  in
        if error == nil {
            self.userRecordID = recordID
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.db.fetch(withRecordID: self.userRecordID) { record, error in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.userRecord = record
                    } else {
                        if let error = error as? CKError {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            if let error = error as? CKError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

This, however, feels messy to me. My question is two-fold: 1) In general, is it acceptable to nest asynchronous calls? 2) If not, is there a better way to accomplish what I want to do in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Its fine to nest asynchronous calls. If call b can't be done until call a has finished then there's no better way really. With your code, if the call to self.container.fetchUserRecordID is already running in a background thread then there's no need for that DispatchQueue wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! I think I see what you mean; so you're saying, why not just perform the fetch(withRecordID:) in the same thread as fetchUserRecordID.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that's DispatchQueue.main, somehow I read it as DispatchQueue.global. You would wrap something in DispatchQueue.main if it needs to run in the main queue. GUI code needs to run in the main queue so if the UI is being updated it must go into the main queue, in your case I presume no UI is being updated, so not only is it unnecessary it ought to be actively avoided as any potentially long running activity shouldn't be performed in the main thread.

Comment: Cool, thanks! That makes sense!